# Custom "Publish" / "Update" button &

Tags: metabox, buttons

I'm trying to implement a "publish" button from a custom post type metabox.  Everything actually works fine if I either create a new button and manually call submit() or duplicate the regular submit buttons, except for one thing:  if i change the title of the post, I always get the "Confirm Navigation" popup asking me if I want tstay or leave the page.  It doesn't do this when using the regular "Update" button though, so there's gotta be a way to stop it, I just can't seem to get a handle on it.

Custom save button using a link:

```
<a href="#" id="saveChangesButton" class="button-primary alignright">Save</a>

// in ready()
$('#saveChangesButton').live('click', function() {
        $('#saveChangesButton').addClass('button-primary-disabled');
        $('#post').submit();
        return false;           
});
```

Custom save buttons trying to mimic the submitdiv's buttons:

```
<?php if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') : ?>
    <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save') ?>" />
    <input name="save" type="submit" class="button-primary" id="publish" tabindex="5" accesskey="p" value="Update">

<?php else: ?>
    <input name="original_publish" type="hidden" id="original_publish" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Publish') ?>" />

    <input name="publish" type="submit" id="publish" class="button-primary" value="Publish" tabindex="5" accesskey="p">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Post some relevant code along with your questions, please.

Comment: added code samples.  Either way I create the buttons, if I change the post's title, I get the "Confirm Navigation" dialog when trying to save.

Comment: Have you seen exactly how the publish link originally works? http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L12, I don't see how your code comes close to this. Are you creating those metaboxes with the [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function?

Comment: All I wanted to do was submit the post from a secondary button, not recreate the entire process. I worked around the issue by disabling autosave for my custom post type and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stimulate click to Update post button like this..
[Adding submit or update button to custom metabox?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/adding-submit-or-update-button-to-custom-metabox)

```
<script>
jQuery('.metabox_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#publish').click();
});
</script>
<input type="submit" class="metabox_submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: that is actually what I wound up doing....way simpler.

Comment: This doesn't seem to publish a new post though, only update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom publish button by using jquery.

```
   <div class = "splw-mbf-banner"></div>  
        
          jQuery('.splw-mbf-banner').append('<input name="publish" type="submit" id="publish" class="publish-button" value="Publish" tabindex="5" accesskey="p">');
```

Also, hide the default publish button by using a simple jQuery code...

```
$('#submitdiv:has(#publish)').css({'display':'none'});
```