# Add a Save Button to Custom Meta Box

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, metabox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding submit or update button to custom metabox?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/adding-submit-or-update-button-to-custom-metabox)

I added a Meta Box Like So:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box('CNMeta', 'Custom MetaBox', 'CNCustomMeta', 'post');
});
```

I also added a thing that saves all of the meta information like this:

```
add_action('save_post', function($id) {
    if(isset($_POST['CNPrice']) ) {
        update_post_meta( $id, 'CNDetails', strip_tags($_POST['CNDetails']) );
    }
});
```

So they can save it by updating the post, it would be nice if I could add a submit button at the bottom of the meta box that also updates the post (and doesn't popup a warning saying "You are about to leave this post unsaved"

How would I do something like that?

Comment: See how the default submit button does, and mimic that?

Comment: Take a look on this answer: [Adding submit or update button to custom metabox?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/adding-submit-or-update-button-to-custom-metabox).

Comment: That answer worked good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a post.

```
<input id="publish" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Update" accesskey="p" tabindex="5" name="save">
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried actually.  It's not a good solution because if the user makes changes to the post and then the user updates the custom meta box (a very common occurence) it will popup a warning message saying that they haven't saved their post.